# How to fetch unique score search result from Elastic Search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to displaying unique 'description' rows from elastic search. I am trying to fetch only one of the rows in many duplicate rows with same description. I don't want to aggregate as i need other information from other columns as well. Below code is what i am trying to achieve but is not working out.

```
  res = esconnection.search(index='data', body={
        # "query": {
        #     "match": {"description": query_input}
        # },
        # "size": 30

        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "description": query_input
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "top-descriptions": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "description"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "top_description_hits": {
                        "top_hits": {
                            "sort": [
                                {
                                    "_score": {
                                        "order": "desc"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "size": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    })
    return res["hits"]["hits"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-collapse) can be used to group documents on a field

> Allows to collapse search results based on field values. The
>   collapsing is done by selecting only the top sorted document per
>   collapse key. For instance the query below retrieves the best tweet
>   for each user and sorts them by number of likes.

**Data**

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "P1lTjHEBF99yL6wF31iA",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "brown fox"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QFlTjHEBF99yL6wF8liO",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "brown fox"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QVlTjHEBF99yL6wF91gU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "brown fox"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QllUjHEBF99yL6wFFFh5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "brown dog"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Q1lUjHEBF99yL6wFGFhQ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "brown dog"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I have three documents with description as "brown fox" and two documents with description as "brown dog"

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": {
        "query": "brown"
      }
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "description.keyword" --> notice keyword
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "P1lTjHEBF99yL6wF31iA",
        "_score" : 0.087011375,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "brown fox"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "description.keyword" : [
            "brown fox"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "QllUjHEBF99yL6wFFFh5",
        "_score" : 0.087011375,
        "_source" : {
          "description" : "brown dog"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "description.keyword" : [
            "brown dog"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Only 2 documents are returned. 
Field collapsing gives features like "inner_hits": if you want to see documents under a group. Using sort you can decide which document to show.

Comment: thankssss alot @jaspreet. This is exactly what i was hunting for days :)